# How to position a child div to span from the beginning to the end of a parent div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flexbox

I'm trying to position the `FullWidthDiv` component to span from the beginning of the `MainDiv` side, all the way to the end. I've tried giving in an absolute position and playing around with flex, but I can't get it to not start from the `SubDiv` component.

Is it possible to achieve this?

My [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-bush-o2z31?file=/src/App.js) approach.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-river-wgfy7?file=/src/App.js) is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: I can't tell where FullWidthDiv begins. The code looks incomplete.

Comment: It's on line 12 in the CodeSandbox link

Comment: This seems a bit "hacky" but you could use negative margins.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit hacky, but you can center `ChildDiv` with `align-items: center`.

Also, shrink the `FullWidthDiv` to 280.
And last you have to add `flex: 1`, `width: 100%` to the div, that hold `SubChildDiv` inside `App` component.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <MainDiv>
      <ChildDiv>
        <div style={{flex: 1, width: '100%'}}>
          <SubChildDiv />
          <SubChildDiv />
        </div>
        <FullWidthDiv />
      </ChildDiv>
    </MainDiv>
  );
}

const MainDiv = ({ children }) => (
  <div
    style={{
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
      width: 250,
      height: 250,
      backgroundColor: "red",
      padding: "1rem"
    }}
  >
    {children}
  </div>
);

const ChildDiv = ({ children }) => (
  <div
    style={{
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection: "column",
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "space-between"
    }}
  >
    {children}
  </div>
);

const SubChildDiv = () => (
  <div
    style={{
      display: "flex",
      width: "100%",
      height: 30,
      backgroundColor: "green",
      border: "1px solid black"
    }}
  />
);

const FullWidthDiv = () => (
  <div
    style={{
      width: 280,
      height: 30,
      border: "1px solid black",
      backgroundColor: "green"
    }}
  />
);
```

If you want the `FullWidthDiv` to be with 100% width, you have to calculate the 100% width and add the padding from both sides of `MainDiv` it will look something like that: `calc(100% + 2rem)`.